# NVDA gainFocus error

Tags: windows

NVDA doesn't read new selected component using tab key. No component change is detected. When hover on component with mouse, text is read. In the NVDA Log there is a message:

ERROR - eventHandler.executeEvent (08:48:55.737):
**error executing event: gainFocus** on  with extra args of {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eventHandler.pyo", line 155, in executeEvent
  File "eventHandler.pyo", line 92, in **init**
  File "eventHandler.pyo", line 100, in next
  File "NVDAObjects\JAB__init__.pyo", line 528, in event_gainFocus
  File "NVDAObjects__init__.pyo", line 1030, in event_gainFocus
  File "NVDAObjects\JAB__init__.pyo", line 476, in reportFocus
  File "NVDAObjects__init__.pyo", line 918, in reportFocus
  File "speech.pyo", line 416, in speakObject
  File "speech.pyo", line 289, in speakObjectProperties
  File "baseObject.pyo", line 47, in **get**
  File "baseObject.pyo", line 147, in _getPropertyViaCache
  File "NVDAObjects\JAB__init__.pyo", line 244, in _get_keyboardShortcut
IndexError: invalid index

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link (again):
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm

I copyed listed files in different locations. When I did that first time I probably missed one file.